# How to grep below match criteria

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, aix

I have a task that requires some logic in order to grep for lines
between a section:

I have in a file the below contents:

```
1856 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_1039

eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 212995
eppix:'informix'.api_valid_token 213201
eppix:'informix'.leads_reasons 213841
eppix:'informix'.epx_vas_sms 214481
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 215121
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 287926
eppix:'informix'.cn_clawback_idx 288750
eppix:'informix'.consent_types_idx 288782
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 288850



1936 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_1119




1937 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_1120




1981 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_1164




1982 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_1165
```

What I need to extract from the file is if I grep for chunkbig10_1039, I would like to print all the lines eppix* and I do not even know where to begin on how to achieve this. The problem is I cannot grep for eppix for example, because that can be anything
but is an example if it were straightforward.

Comment: what is your expected output? based on what you explained you just need `grep 'eppix' infile` (since there is nowhere in your given sample input lines having that string to match); so update your input sample as well as show expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{ f=/chunkbig10_1039/; next } f && NF' file
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 212995
eppix:'informix'.api_valid_token 213201
eppix:'informix'.leads_reasons 213841
eppix:'informix'.epx_vas_sms 214481
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 215121
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 287926
eppix:'informix'.cn_clawback_idx 288750
eppix:'informix'.consent_types_idx 288782
eppix:'informix'.lsc_ix1 288850
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> … I would like to print all the lines eppix* …

Well, as αғsнιη points out, you can do that (for the given input) with

```
grep 'eppix' infile
```

In fact, ***for the given input**,* you can get the desired result with

```
printf "eppix:'informix'.%s\n" 'lsc_ix1 212995' 'api_valid_token 213201' 'leads_reasons 213841' \
                        'epx_vas_sms 214481' 'lsc_ix1 215121' 'lsc_ix1 287926' \
                        'cn_clawback_idx 288750' 'consent_types_idx 288782' 'lsc_ix1 288850'
```

But you also say

> … grep for lines between a section

so I *guess* you mean that you want to restrict your search
to the lines between `chunkbig10_1039` and the next `chunkbig10_`. 
And, since you say

> … I would like to print all the lines eppix* …

I’m going to make the radical assumption that
you want to print all the lines containing `eppix`
that are between `chunkbig10_1039` and the next `chunkbig10_`,
and that there might be other non-blank lines there.

**If this isn’t what you want,
please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/664382/edit) your question
to explain what you want more clearly.**

We can do that with a single invocation of `sed`:

```
sed -n '/chunkbig10_1039/,/chunkbig10_/ { /eppix/p }' infile
```

- `sed n` means “don’t print everything; just print what we say to print.”
- `/eppix/p` means “print every line that contains `eppix`”, and
- `/chunkbig10_1039/,/chunkbig10_/ { … }` means
  “do the commands between `{` and `}` only for the lines
  between the one matching `chunkbig10_1039`
  and the next one matching `chunkbig10_`.”

I made a simpler (easier to read) input file that exhibits my assumptions
(and lack thereof):

```
$ cat infile
eppix ant
chunkbig10_1
bat
eppix cat
dog
eppix elk

chunkbig10_2
eppix fox
gopher
horse
chunkbig10_3
impala
eppix jaguar
kangaroo
eppix llama

$ sed -n '/chunkbig10_1/,/chunkbig10_/ { /eppix/p }' infile
eppix cat
eppix elk

$ sed -n '/chunkbig10_2/,/chunkbig10_/ { /eppix/p }' infile
eppix fox

$ sed -n '/chunkbig10_3/,/chunkbig10_/ { /eppix/p }' infile
eppix jaguar
eppix llama
```

- If you want to find only lines that *begin* with `eppix`, say so.
- If you want to find all non-blank lines in the “section”, say so.
- If you might have lines that contain `chunkbig10_1039 foo`, say so.
- If you might have lines that contain `chunkbig10_1039bar`
  (or `chunkbig10_103942`), say so.
- If

  ```
  chunkbig10_2
  ```

  doesn’t end a section, but it has to be

  ```
  1983 /dev/informix/chunkbig10_2
  ```

  say so.
- If you might have lines that contain `chunkbig10_` ***and also*** `eppix`,
  say what you want to do with them.

Answer (score -2):

```
sed -n -e '/chunkbig10_1039/,/chunkbig10_*/ p' test|grep -v 'chunkbig'
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any time you use a pipeline that includes any 2 or more of grep, sed, and/or awk you should be using a single awk script instead.